# How to create a TcpClient in C# that can recover from a lost network connection?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I am trying to write a TCP client thread that will connect to a server and continue to process data as it receives it.  Sometimes the client will lose connection to the server.  When the connection is re-established, the thread should resume/recover and automatically start processing data again.  I can't seem to get this to work. The basic algorithm is below.  My problem is that I just don't quite understand how the TcpClient behaves when the network connection is lost.  How can I tell that the connection has been lost?  Do I then need to close the connection?  How do I reestablish the connection and continue on?

```
TcpClient _tcpClient;
IPEndPoint _ipEndPoint;
bool _cancelled = false;
bool _error = true;
while (!_cancelled)
{
  try
  {
    if(_error)
    {
      _ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(_myAddress, _myPort);
      _tcpClient.Connect(_ipEndPoint);
      _networkStream = _tcpClient.GetStream();
      _error = false;
    }
    else
    {
      _data = new byte[10025];
      if(_networkStream.CanRead)
      {
        _bytesRead = _networkStream.Read(_data, 0, (int)_tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
        if(_bytesRead > 0)
        {
          ...process the data...
        }
        else
        {
          _error = true;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        _error = true;
      }
    }
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    ...log error...
    _error = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahh the joys and pains of networking. Look into message queuing. You'll have to keep track of what got sent and received on the client and server by adding messages into a collection. When a message is received, queue another message acknowledging the message was received so the client can remove it from the queue. You'll need to continue to loop your attempt to reconnect if the connection is closed.

Comment: you can read source code tcp library for handling such pain http://nitoasync.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

there is a Connected property on the TcpClient, but it is only updated when a Write or Read is executed on the NetworkStream.

I think you can just execute a Read(null,0,0) or Write(null,0,0) if you want to force a connectivity check. But in the example you have you can check the Connected or CanRead properties after your _networkStream.Read is completed.

As for reestablishing the link what you have will work. I would suggest Disposing of the old network stream before getting a new one. Something like this:

```
if(_networkStream != null)
{
   _networkStream.Dispose();
}
_networkStream = _tcpClient.GetStream();
```

What I do is start a reconnect timer that will attempt to reconnect on a configured interval. Depending on the TcpHost your connecting to you may even want to start trying at a small interval 500-1000ms and increment is after a given number of failed retries so your not wasting a lot of time trying to connect to a host that is gone. Then after a max number of tries just give up unless the user explicitly requests to try again. But that also depends on what else your app is doing, if the connection is its sole purpose or if its just one piece.

The wrapper class I use to interact with TcpClient is around 700 lines of code and it handles reconnects, sending data as well as reading it. I work in a closed shop so i cant post it but if you have any other specific question I'd be happy to help.

Good luck.